# Why does smplayer always resume at the same spot for some video files?

Tags: video, mplayer

I have smplayer setup so that it resumes videos from wherever it left off.

However, I have a few files that when I play them with smplayer, they always get resumed from the same spot.

Why does it do that, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

`smplayer` can optionally remember, for each file it plays, where it was in the video or audio file when it exited.

This can be enabled or disabled with:

**Options** menu -> **Preferences** -> **General** tab, "**Remember Time Position**" checkbox.